Proof of analytic continuation on manifold
I was reading the theorem below in this article. My question concerns the passages in bold. Specifically, why would Z be open? Is it because we can use germs to define a topology where Z would be the intersection of open sets?
The other question is why the fact that power series representations are unique in the convergence domain implies that Z is closed. I was imagining that the continuity of f would be used to define ${z\in D\mid f=0}$ as closed.
Theorem 5.1 (The Principle of Analytic Continuation) Suppose that $p \in M$, $f \in O^{anal}_
{M}$ , and $[f]_p = 0$ in $O^{anal}_{M,p}$. Then, $f = 0$ in $O^{anal}_{M}$.
Proof. Let $Z := {x \in M | [f]_{x} = 0}$. Then, $Z$ is non-empty (since $p \in Z$) and is clearly open in $M$. However, as power series representations of functions are unique on the domain of convergence, $Z$ is also closed in M. As $M$ is connected and non-empty, $Z = M$, i.e., $f = 0$ in $O^{anal}_{M}$.
One last question on this subject, I would like to ask for references on analytic sets, particularly regarding this result concerning analytic continuity for a manifold M.
